# emberjs go to anchor from another view

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js, ember-cli

Currently I am using the [ember cli](http://iamstef.net/ember-cli/) project to build my ember application, but I am running into an issue trying to configure my navigation. The following code block works on the index router, however, I am running into an issue on my other routers.  The goToAnchor section allows me to navigate to in page anchor tags on a single infinite scroll like home page, but when I go to other views i.e. my /terms page I need the menu to be able to click back to the home page, ideally without refreshing the browser.

Is this possible without the refresh?

Index Router:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    actions: {
        goToAnchor: function(item,anchor) {
            var $elem, $scrollTo;
            $elem = $('#' + anchor);
            $scrollTo = $('body').animate({
                scrollTop: $elem.offset().top-15
            }, parseInt(ENV.CONFIG.PRODUCT.SCROLL_SPEED));
            this.transitionTo(item.route).then($scrollTo);
        }
    }
});
```

Navigation:

```
<section class="top-bar-section center">
    <ul class="nav-header">
        <li><a {{action goToAnchor 'index' 'menu1'}}>menu1</a></li>
        <li><a {{action goToAnchor 'index' 'menu2'}}>menu2</a></li>
        <li><a {{action goToAnchor 'index' 'menu3'}}>menu3</a></li>
        <li><a {{action goToAnchor 'index' 'menu4'}}>menu4</a></li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

Current setup at the time of this post:

```
DEBUG: ------------------------------- 
DEBUG: Ember      : 1.5.1 
DEBUG: Ember Data : 1.0.0-beta.7+canary.b45e23ba 
DEBUG: Handlebars : 1.3.0 
DEBUG: jQuery     : 2.1.1 
DEBUG: -------------------------------
```

Comment: I'm not getting your problem. A simple jsfiddle may help

Comment: it is rather hard to describe, but I have the index view where the goToAnchors work, however, on other views, how do I make the menu link back to the index view?

Comment: So you click a link-to to go to a view, but how does the new menu work so it can click back to the home with the anchor?

Comment: When you want to transition to any route from handlebars templates, you should make use of `link-to` helper. 
http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/links/

Comment: Also have a look at this post to preserve the scrolling position
http://reefpoints.dockyard.com/2014/05/05/preserve-scroll-position-in-ember-apps.html

Comment: If the above two doesn't help you, its clear that i'm no where near your problem. I'm happy to help incase you provide a simple working fiddle/jsbin.

Comment: I will setup a test repo @selvagsz tomorrow and post the link here, would be easier than jsfiddle.  thank you so far.

Comment: heya @selvagsz here is the repo with the test code :: https://github.com/chrishough/embercli-emberjs-test  Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Chris I had just looked into your code and was able to identify the gotchas

1. Your terms page's route is `legal/tou`. When you click the navigation menu from the terms page, you action is bubbled via `legal/tou => application` routes (child => parent hierarchy). Hence the `Nothing handled in the action goToAnchor` was thrown. So first step is to move up your `goToAnchor` logic from `index` route to `application` route.
2. Secondly, in the `goToAnchor` action you are trying to query the DOM before the template gets rendered. Hence, it blows up. You need to query the DOM after the template is rendered. You should make use of `afterRender` queue of Ember RunLoop. To know more about Ember Runloops refer the [docs here](http://emberjs.com/guides/understanding-ember/run-loop/)

   ```
   //routes/application.js

   export default Ember.Route.extend({
   actions: {
    goToAnchor: function(route,anchor) {
       var $elem, $scrollTo;
       this.transitionTo(route).then(function() {
         Em.run.schedule('afterRender', function(){
           $elem = $('#' + anchor);
           $('html,body').animate({
               scrollTop: $elem.offset().top-15
           }, 500);              
         });
       });
     }
    }
   });
   ```